# Paper.js анимирование одного path в другой path

Tags: svg, анимация, canvas, path

Как с помощью `paper.js` можно анимировать один `path` в другой `path`, которые  заранее известны?

```html
    var path1 = "M2337.8,0.1c-346.8,7.6-415.8,270.8-934.3,244.7 c-330.4-16.6-389.1-110.8-677.8-101.3c-321,10.5-403.4,252.6-592.3,252.6C73,396.1,29.8,372.8,0,341.9v451.8h2778V200 C2692.9,103.1,2538.6-4.3,2337.8,0.1z"
    path2 = "M2337.8,326.3C1991,333.9,1845,45.9,1472,45.9 c-334.4,0-390,181.9-639,181.9C473,227.8,400.3,0,195.7,0C84.5,0,0,98.3,0,146.1v562.6h2778V62.9 C2686,199.8,2538.6,321.9,2337.8,326.3z"
```

Comment: Коды каких патчей?

Comment: Отредактировал, добавил path

Comment: @Alexandr_TT, почта России?))))

Answer (score 2):

Вот ваш svg, в котором патчами нарисованы две кривые.

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
   
     width="500" height="500" viewBox="0 0 500 500" >  
<g fill="none" stroke="black">
 <path d= "M2337.8,0.1c-346.8,7.6-415.8,270.8-934.3,244.7 c-330.4-16.6-389.1-110.8-677.8-101.3c-321,10.5-403.4,252.6-592.3,252.6C73,396.1,29.8,372.8,0,341.9v451.8h2778V200 C2692.9,103.1,2538.6-4.3,2337.8,0.1z"/>

 <path d= "M2337.8,326.3C1991,333.9,1845,45.9,1472,45.9 c-334.4,0-390,181.9-639,181.9C473,227.8,400.3,0,195.7,0C84.5,0,0,98.3,0,146.1v562.6h2778V62.9 C2686,199.8,2538.6,321.9,2337.8,326.3z" />
 </g>
</svg>
```

Как я понимаю, вы хотели, чтобы одна кривая плавно трансформировалась в другую кривую.

Для этого нужно сделать анимацию параметра `d` патча.
 Другими словами все узловые точки первого патча должны переместиться из позиций первого патча в позиции второго патча. 
Для этого существует команда анимации:

```
<animate attributeName="d" dur="4s" begin="svg1.click" fill="freeze" values="M2337.8,0.1c-346.8 первый патч .....z; M2337.8,326.3C1991... второй патч ..z />
```

Обратите внимание на точку с запятой - **`z;`** это обязательное разделение двух патчей, которые будут трансформироваться

Анимация начинается по клику на холсте svg  `begin="svg1.click"`

```html
<svg id="svg1" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="500" height="500" viewBox="0 0 500 500" >  
<g fill="none" stroke="black">
 <path d= "M2337.8,0.1c-346.8,7.6-415.8,270.8-934.3,244.7 c-330.4-16.6-389.1-110.8-677.8-101.3c-321,10.5-403.4,252.6-592.3,252.6C73,396.1,29.8,372.8,0,341.9v451.8h2778V200 C2692.9,103.1,2538.6-4.3,2337.8,0.1z">  
 
<animate attributeName="d" dur="4s" begin="svg1.click" fill="freeze" values="M2337.8,0.1c-346.8,7.6-415.8,270.8-934.3,244.7 c-330.4-16.6-389.1-110.8-677.8-101.3c-321,10.5-403.4,252.6-592.3,252.6C73,396.1,29.8,372.8,0,341.9v451.8h2778V200 C2692.9,103.1,2538.6-4.3,2337.8,0.1z;M2337.8,326.3C1991,333.9,1845,45.9,1472,45.9 c-334.4,0-390,181.9-639,181.9C473,227.8,400.3,0,195.7,0C84.5,0,0,98.3,0,146.1v562.6h2778V62.9 C2686,199.8,2538.6,321.9,2337.8,326.3z " />
</path>
 </g>
</svg>
```

**На мой взгляд просто необходимо разобраться, как происходят трансформации в чистом SVG, а потом уже использовать JS фреймворки.**

Часто бывает, что при использовании фреймворка анимация svg не работает и тут остается только гадать, где причина отказа - ошибки svg или ошибки в использовании фреймворка.

Comment: Это все конечно замечательно, но это я все примерно знаю. Мне нужна информация именно по библиотеке, потому что она работает с канвас. Я знаю что она может генерировать пас в канвас, а вот как сделать морфлинг я в  документации какой то вменяемой информации не нашел, но исходя из их примеров, это сделать можно